# Read Http Cookie from Request Stream In a WCF Service

Tags: wcf

What settings must be configured to permit Http cookies to retrieved from the Http request object in a WCF service. I am using basic Http binding. I have set aspNetCompatibilityEnabled = true and  allowCookies="true". Please advise. I am certain the cookie is there with the proper domain. I have created an .aspx test page that calls my utility directly and the cookie value is returned, but calling the same code wrapped in a service does not return a value.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using :

`HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["CookieName"]`?

If you are using this then there no problem. 
And make sure that there is no spelling mistake.

If you are using form authentication then you have to pass token for authentication.

Comment: i still cannot get cookie when cosume in same domain, however when i am manually posting it in adrees bar it is capturing cookie